# ignore leading zeros and read the rest with flex analyzer

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I want to ignore the leading zeros of an integer
lets say I have 00034 I want to accept only 43 and ignore the zeros.
I am using flex and I want to return a token for the integer 43

```
NUMBER [1-9][0-9]*|0
ZEROS 00+
```

and then:

```
{ZEROS}  { /*DO NOTHING*/ } 
{NUMBER} { return INT; }
```

but there is a problem with those because when I try 0032 I get the correct result but when I try 032 it returns 0 as an int and 32 as an int.

if I use:

```
NUMBER [1-9][0-9]*|0
ZEROS 00*
```

The single zero are ignored.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? You don't return the text. You return the token `INT`, and you should also be storing `atoi(yyext)` into `yylval`. *That's* what takes care of the leading zeros. Not the analyser. Your rule should be:

```
[0-9]+ { yylval.intValue = atoi(yytext); return INT; }
```